# LT1013 voltage supply operation

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

How can I tell if the LT1013 will work with -4.5 volt and +4.5 volt supply voltage?

In the datasheet just says that it works with 0 and 5 volt, and -15 and +15.

Answer (score 2):

[Page 4 of the datasheet says it will operate on any voltage difference from 5 to 30 Volts between Vcc+ and Vcc-.](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=lt1013&fileType=pdf)

That means Vcc- at 0 and Vcc+ at 5V is fine.

It also means -4.5V to 4.5V is fine.

You need to check the restrictions on input and output voltages, though.

It doesn't appear to be rail to rail on output.  Input range doesn't appear to include the rails, either.

---

The business with it not being rail to rail means it will do things you don't expect in certain conditions if you are thinking of it like an ideal opamp.

Since the inputs aren't rail to rail, it will begin misbehaving if your signal input voltage gets to close to Vcc+ or Vcc-.  If, for example, you are operating on 0-5V and put the positive input at 2.5V and the other at 0.5V, the output might not be 2.0V as you would expect.

The thing about the output not being rail to rail means that (using the same supply voltages as before) that if you arrange the inputs to produce a 0V output, the output won't actually be 0V.

Comment: Rail to rail inputs have their own pitfalls; if it is not a necessary feature, don't use that type.